# Clean & Trim Cell VBA returning #Value

Tags: vba, excel

I have been using the below code on a workbook to clean up cells which contain a lot of text. It has worked well until recently when the content in a single cell increased significantly. In turn, instead of removing the excess spaces it instead changes the content of the cell to #value. This only happens in cells with a lot of content.

I was wondering if anyone could help shed some light on why this might be happening? I haven't been able to resolve it.

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim Area As Range
Dim msg As String

'Selects range to be trimmed
Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("B14:B2500,D14:E2500,G14:K2500")

'Trim and Clean cell values
For Each Area In rng.Areas
Area.Value = Evaluate("IF(ROW(" & Area.Address & "),CLEAN(TRIM(" & Area.Address & ")))")
Next Area

MsgBox ("Complete")
End Sub
```

Many Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `Evaluate("=IF(ROW(" & Area.Address & "),CLEAN(TRIM(" & Area.Address & ")))")`. Seems you may have forgot the `=`?

Comment: How much is "a lot"? I don't know but perhaps there is a limit.

Comment: Why don't you use a simple loop and trim? You know that clean may not be able to solve some of the issues. Sometimes there are invisible characters and clean is not able to handle so even if your solution works, it is not 100% guaranteed you will get clean values in the cells

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the same problem with this formula.  When I reviewed the options for formulas for that workbook R1C1 reference style was checked.  I unchecked it and the formula works.